# Place Subtotal value in all cells in group

Tags: excel, excel-formula, subtotal, vba

I have a requirement where i need to enter the value of a SubTotal in each row for the corresponding group. Below is a snapshot of the subtotals in in Column Q and this value manualy entered by me in Column M. I'm happy to create a Macro to do this or a Formula, but i can not seem to think of the logic on how to achieve this. Can anyone advise please.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Did either the answers work for you?  If so please mark the one with which you went as the correct answer.  you do this by clicking on the green check mark by the correct answer.  It will close the question as answered.  It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following **Array Formula** in M5:

```
=IF(A5<>"",INDEX($Q5:$Q$1000,MATCH(0,IF($A5:$A$1000="",0,1),0)),"")
```

**Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter or Tab to exit edit mode**.  Then copy down.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Scott, works like a dream. I have used Index Match before, but not quite like this and i have to say that i'm still unsure as to the logic, but i will endeavour to work it out.

Answer (score 2):

This formula worked for me:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A5),"",IF(OR(ISBLANK(A4),A4="Ship-to Pt"),INDEX(Q:Q,MATCH(A5,A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A:A,A5)),M4))
```

Drag down the dataset.

You can set specific row limits if desired.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this did not work for me, only because i did not explain that column A is not unique and therefore it returns the first value that matches.